# Calling functions outside class

Tags: vb.net

what is the correct way to call function  outside the class, below code is also working

tried an alternate way by using delegate but couldn't figure out to pass function with parameters from Form class to classname so that form function can be called.

```
Public class form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dim cl as new classname
        cl.run()
    end sub

    function testmsg(txt as string)
        msgbox(txt)
    end function

end class

public class classname
    public sub run()
        txt = "xyz"
        if(condition = true) then call form1.testmsg(byref txt as string)
    end sub
end class
```

Comment: The most appropriate way there would probably be to have your object raise an event that the form can handle.  That actually is using a delegate but in a special way.

Comment: IMHO, the structure needs to be re-designed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at any time, and in any place, and from a form, a class object, or even just standard vb module call/use a function (or in your case, it should be a sub).

Just mark any routine (sub/function) in the form as public.

eg:

```
Public function testmsg(txt as string)
    msgbox(txt)
end function
```

NOw, in any other form, class or in fact any place you have code, you can thus go:

```
    FormA.TestMsg("hi from form B")
```

so, there are no restrictions here. And any form wide scoped variables marked as public can also be used:

eg:

```
Public Class FormA


   Public Zoo As String

   Public Function TestMsg(txt As String)
       MsgBox(txt)
   End Function

   Public Sub ShowZoo()
       MsgBox("value of zoo = " & Zoo)
   End Sub

End Class
```

So above is FormA

Now, any code from any ohter form, class or whatever can do this:

```
    FormA.TestMsg("hi from form B")
    FormA.Zoo = "this is zoo value"
    FormA.ShowZoo()
```

So, just mark any variable as public (it in effect becomes a public property of that form).

And, just mark any function/Sub as pubic (it in effect becomes a public "method" of that form.

Comment: My code is also working in the same way you mentioned but wanted to check if that is the correct way or should i use delegate sub.

Comment: Well, I can't really vouch for the correct way but, yes, simply marking the class variables or sub/functions as public is all that is required. So, I can't really imagine any real benefit of an alternative approach. I would suggest that such code is to be called from several places then consider moving the the code in question to a standard code module - often not even a class is required.